# importing a book from to iPhotos back into iPhotos

Tags: macbook-pro, import

I created a book in iphotos. Then i exported it as a pdf file to desktop. I deleted it from iPhotos. I now want to add more pages to the book. Can I take it back to iPhotos and complete the book and how?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't reimport the PDF. You should still have the photos in your library and you can use the PDF to guide you in recreating the book.